# Pass listview selected text to another activity

Tags: android, listview

Sorry Guys having trouble getting this to work, Error occurs during the onclick event. I want to pass the selected text back to the initiating activity. I am new at this so go easy please :)

```
public class selectTee extends ListActivity{

    String[] tees_list;
    String value = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tees_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tees_array);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_view, tees_list));
        final ListView teelist = getListView();
        teelist.setChoiceMode(1);
        teelist.setTextFilterEnabled(false);
        teelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> teeAdapter, View arg1, int selectedInt, long selectedLong) {

                //Error occurs during the onclick event
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra(value, selectedInt);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Ok I got it to work I changed the following code:**

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
            {

```
            if (requestCode == request_Code) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Button revisedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                String btext = data.getData().toString(); 
                revisedButton.setText((CharSequence) btext);

            }

            }
        }
```

And the returning activity

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> teeAdapter, View arg1, int selectedInt, long selectedLong) {
            String selection  =((TextView) arg1).getText().toString();
            System.out.println(selection);
            Intent data = new Intent();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(selection);
            System.out.println(uri);
            data.setData(uri);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }



    });
```

Comment: what's the error. The log will help.

Comment: 12-05 17:47:40.781: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { cmp=com.prophecysoftware.GolfProphecy/.SetupNewCourse (has extras) }} to activity {com.prophecysoftware.GolfProphecy/com.prophecysoftware.GolfProphecy.SetupNewCourse}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YOUCLASS.class);
intent.putExtra("TEXT", selectedInt);
//startActivity(intent) if you want to start an activity when its clicked
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're never setting "value" so it would still be null. I think that might be your problem.  Can you try setting that String value before calling putExtra?

Also, to get the selected text from the view clicked. do the following:

```
String textOfSelectedItem  =((TextView) arg1).getText().toString();
```